# Mocking external API in Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am trying to mock external api in Django but not sure how to do it properly.

Basically, it must mock the json data from external API and then create a new object if all values are valid.

The program fetches the geolocation data based on given IP address and saves the object in database if response data includes all required fields. So, how I can mock this process to test a new object creation?

**services.py**

```
import os
import requests
from .exceptions import ExternalApiException

def get_location(ip):
    url = f'http://api.ipstack.com/{ip}' 
    params = {'access_key': os.environ.get('ACCESS_KEY')}
    try:
        res = requests.get(url, params=params)
        data = res.json()
        return {
            'ip':data['ip'],
            'country_name':data['country_name'],
            'region_code':data['region_code'],
            'city':data['city'],
            'latitude':data['latitude'],
            'longitude':data['longitude'],
            'zip_code':data['zip']
        }
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        raise ExternalApiException('Connection error occured during the fetch process')
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        raise ExternalApiException("Connection timeout. Please check your internet connection and try again later")
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        raise ExternalApiException("Too many redirects")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        raise SystemExit(e)
```

**tests.py**

```
#I am lost in this part

@patch('geolocation.services.get_location')
def test_create_basic_geolocation(self, mock_request):
        """Test creating geolocation data"""
        payload = { 
            'ip': '',
        }
        res = self.client.post(LOCATIONS_URL, payload)

        self.assertTrue(res.data['ip'])
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assign return_value on mocked instance like this

```
@patch('geolocation.services.get_location')
def test_create_basic_geolocation(self, mock_request):
        """Test creating geolocation data"""
        mock_request.return_value = {"ip": "hello", "country_name": "test"}
        payload = { 
            'ip': '',
        }
        res = self.client.post(LOCATIONS_URL, payload)

        self.assertTrue(res.data['ip'])
```

Comment: Oh okay I get the idea and it works now, thanks